# select for update not working using jdbc template (posgres)

Tags: java, postgresql, asynchronous, locking, jdbctemplate

I want multiple instances of my java code to read the same set of data, and i want to lock the records(row level) read by first instance. So that the second instance wont read the same data. here is my sample code which doesnt work. I get the same records if i read twice at the same time.For testing purpose I create list 1 and list 2 and read twice one after another to simulate multiple instances reading the same data.

```
    query = "SELECT  * from xyz LIMIT 10  FOR UPDATE of xyz"

            List<XYZ> list1= new ArrayList<XYZ>();
    List<XYZ> list2= new ArrayList<XYZ>();

    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);

    TransactionStatus s=datasourceconfig.platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);

    try {
        list1= datasourceconfig.queryForObjectList(query , paramMap ,XYZ.class);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("", ex);
    }

    try {
        list2= datasourceconfig.queryForObjectList(query,paramMap,XYZ.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("", ex);
    }

    empDsCfg.platformTransactionManager.commit(s);
```

When i get the result, both the list have the same records. Kindly help.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what `FOR UPDATE` locks are for. They (generally) just blocks **other** transactions to modify the selected rows (but never *hides* them). If you read the rows in the same transaction, this blocking would never occur. Also, it works kind of differently in the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation. Please read carefully the [docs about transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). We can only just repeat, what's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on PostgreSQL 9.5 or later, you can use

```
SELECT ...
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

which will select and lock up to ten rows that are not already locked by a concurrent transaction.

An alternative that can be used with all PostgreSQL versions is to use advisory locks like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(id)
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE;
```

Here `id` is the primary key, and it is assumed that it is an integer value (a type that can implicitly be cast to `bigint`).

This function returns `TRUE` if there is no exclusive [*advisory lock*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) with that number yet and grabs the lock as a side effect.

**Note:** locks only hold for the duration of a transaction, so be sure to do the lock and the subsequent data modification in a single transaction.

Comment: the skip locked worked on 9.5 but had to add begin and end/commit for it to work

Comment: I thought that was understood, but I have added a note to make it clear.